# how to configure shared web hosting on ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, server, web-hosting

i am planning to open a shared web hosting company. before opening i am configuring and checking that all things are up and running or not.

i had tried webmin, virtualmin and ajenti as web hosting manager on ubuntu server but i am not satisfied with them. is there any alternative to them which have secure administrator and client side control panel and easier to manager client account and hosts.

i am using apache2 as web server and mysql as database serve.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try ZPanel, it is cross-platform and has a great looking control panel. They also provide an installer which installs Apache, PHP, MySQL, and ZPanel, all pre-configured to run a shared hosting service.

[Link](http://www.zpanelcp.com/)

Comment: i had tried to install zpanel but its not supporting ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Detected : Ubuntu  14.04  64
Sorry, this installer only supports the installation of ZPanel on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: There's an installer for Ubuntu 14.04 in their [Github repo](https://github.com/zpanel/installers/blob/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS/ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh), but it is in beta. Perhaps, you can try to configure it [manually](http://www.zpanelcp.com/download/) (Look for the "Other operating systems").

Answer (score 0):

Getting shared hosting right isn't an easy thing to do especially if you want to allow your clients to use scripting languages like PHP. By default, PHP runs under the same userid regardless of which of customer the files belong to. So they will be able to see the files (including config files with database passwords) of the other customers.

There are ways around this problem, but most of them are either inconvenient for the customer or they bring other problems (like having to run the Apache as root).

Besides the shared hosting market is quite full with existing companies which have huge data centers and therefore can offer much more service at lower costs.

So my suggestion would be: Look at new services that you can provide. Docker Hosting or LXC Hosting isn't that common yet and you can better compete there.

If you really want to do simple shared hosting, and are in search of an admin tool: Try ISPCONFIG3

Comment: thanx for your suggession :) i will try ISPCONFIG3 @nbkr